# Cannot play HLS in Next.js 13

Tags: reactjs, next.js, http-live-streaming, video.js

I just want to play a simple HLS stream with video.js. First of all, I created a simple HTML file with the following code:

```
<head>
  <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/8.3.0/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>

<body>
  <video
    id="my-video"
    class="video-js"
    controls
    preload="auto"
    width="640"
    height="264"
    poster="MY_VIDEO_POSTER.jpg"
    data-setup="{}"
  >
    <source src="https://ntv1.akamaized.net/hls/live/2014075/NASA-NTV1-HLS/master_500.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegurl" />
    <p class="vjs-no-js">
      To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a
      web browser that
      <a href="https://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank"
        >supports HTML5 video</a
      >
    </p>
  </video>

  <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/8.3.0/video.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

If you copy and paste the code above into an HTML and open that static file on the browser, it will play the NASA stream just fine.

However, when I try to play the same URL on my NextJS app I get the following error:

```
GET https://ntv1.akamaized.net/hls/live/2014075/NASA-NTV1-HLS/master_500.m3u8 403 (Forbidden)
```

I use Next.JS 13 and I try to render the player components on the client side. However, I still get the same error. Here is my video Player component:

```
  'use client';
  import videojs from 'video.js';
  import 'video.js/dist/video-js.css';
  import 'videojs-contrib-hls';
  import { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

  const MyVideoPlayer = () => {
    const videoRef = useRef<any>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
      if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        // Code to run on the client-side
        const player = videojs(videoRef.current);
        player.src({
          src: 'https://ntv1.akamaized.net/hls/live/2014075/NASA-NTV1-HLS/master_500.m3u8',
          type: 'application/x-mpegURL',
        });
      }

      return () => {
        if (videoRef.current) {
          videojs(videoRef.current).dispose();
        }
      };
    }, []);

    return (
      <div data-vjs-player>
        <video ref={videoRef} className='video-js'></video>
      </div>
    );
  };

  export default MyVideoPlayer;
```

And this is my page.tsx code:

```
'use client';
import React from 'react';
import MyVideoPlayer from '../videoPlayer';
export default function PlayerPage() {
  const playerRef = React.useRef(null);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Welcome to the player page</h1>
      <MyVideoPlayer />
    </>
  );
}
```

What am I doing wrong?